# Why does a Node.js heapdump shows compiled code?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, v8

Hi first time at investigating memory leak in a Node.js application.  By reading thru a heapdump snapshot in Chrome Profiler, I see that there is an entry for (compiled code), see attached.  I thought Javascript is not compiled, unlike Java.  Can anyone shed some lights?

[image]

Further, unlike JProfiler and with the way the code was written (without a formal constructor), it is very hard to find the leak, and so far the info the snapshot provides is not quite useful, I have searched for sometime and so far not too much useful info on reading these snapshots, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`(compiled code)` indeed refers to the code generated by V8's JIT compiler. All JavaScript VMs employed by browsers today are using tiered adaptive JIT compilation - it wouldn't be possible to achieve good performance otherwise. In fact V8 never had an interpreter at all.

Comment: V8 does include an interpreter, which runs code before compiling it

Comment: Yes, today it does. That interpreter was added in ~2016.

Answer (score -2):

That refers to host objects that are implemented in C++, such as the DOM, or the JS built-in functions.